# Application of sylow theorem on symmetric group S_5

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

> Show that $S_5$ has a normal subgroup $H$ such that $S_5/H$ is of order $20$

I think if there exist such H then the order of $H$ should be $6$ .
And order of $S_5$ is $5!$ Ie $120$ and so $S_5$ has sylow $2$ subgroup of order $8$ and a sylow $3$ subgroup and a sylow $5$ subgroup so how can I prove that there exist a normal subgroup of order $6$?

Comment: You can explicitly write down such a subgroup. If the subgroup is order 6, think about what that means for cycle shape

Comment: Cycle shape is  of (abc)(de) type

Comment: The only normal subgroups of $S_5$ are 1, $A_5$, and $S_5$....

Comment: I agree with @ArturoMagidin. Are you sure you have written this question correctly? Where did you get this question from?

Comment: Yes..https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BvCvb2m9Z99jG1CZOObqSLuqKCPad_9-/view?usp=drivesdk
Link for question paper...pdf page no 15, question no M6

Comment: Your reference gives me "Access Denied". But if the question is as you state it is then  as others have said it is  just plain wrong.

Comment: Okay thank you 